# Fastest hard drive scan with Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to get my Windows Store App to scan the hard drive of my user, looking for files with a particular extension, so that my app is able to display them in an internal menu. Obviously, due to the permissions necessary, the user has to initially use a FolderPicker to indicate the root of a drive he wants to scan.

Sadly, all of the approaches I've found on MSDN result in very poor performance. The page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994634.aspx has the example below as the better performing alternative for a simple folder enumeration task. You can easily adapt it to handle scanning a whole drive by using a `QueryOptions` object with the `FolderDepth` property set to `FolderDepth.Deep`, then have the user point the root folder.

```
// Set QueryOptions to prefetch our specific properties
var queryOptions = new Windows.Storage.Search.QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, null);
queryOptions.SetThumbnailPrefetch(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 100,
        ThumbnailOptions.ReturnOnlyIfCached);
queryOptions.SetPropertyPrefetch(PropertyPrefetchOptions.ImageProperties, 
       new string[] {"System.Size"});

StorageFileQueryResult queryResults = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResults.GetFilesAsync();


foreach (var file in files)
{
    ImageProperties imageProperties = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();

    // Do something with the date the image was taken.
    DateTimeOffset dateTaken = imageProperties.DateTaken;

    // Performance gains increase with the number of properties that are accessed.
    IDictionary<String, object> propertyResults =
        await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(
              new string[] {"System.Size" });

    // Get/Set extra properties here
    var systemSize = propertyResults["System.Size"];

}
```

For a normal HDD with about 50GB of data, this approach can take up to 5~10 minutes, which is really unacceptable. Weirdly enough, however, performing a windows search for that filetype has the query returning in less than 30 seconds, which means there is room for performance gain somewhere.

Does anybody know of a way of doing this task any faster?

Comment: Where is the time being spent?

Comment: In
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResults.GetFilesAsync();
Waiting for GetFilesAsync to return

Answer (score 0):

Windows Search have the prebuild indexes for folders and files (that this service monitor). To reach this performance you should build your own index and use it later. There is no way to speedup linear scanning and waiting in `GetFilesAsync` is the sign of maximum performance from the side of your app.

Comment: GetFilesAsync is guaranteed to be the fastest scanning approach possible? Maybe if I used another library that did file access outside of the Windows Runtime?

Comment: GetFilesAsync works inside windows libs and there is nothing to tweak or optimize. The bottleneck is in filesystem.